# Remove elements with fixed percentage from a list of sub-lists in Python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have the following list:

```
    list = [[0.002, 0.001, 0.055, 0.44, 0.11, 0.002, 0.001, 0.055, 0.44, 0.11],
            [0.001, 0.006, 0.009, 0.002, 0.33],
            [0.02, 0.004,0.003, 0.001, 0.008]]
```

I want to preserve 20% of the elements for each sub-list, and delete the list elements from the beginning of the sub-lists, so the result will look like:

```
    list = [[0.055, 0.44, 0.11, 0.002, 0.001, 0.055, 0.44, 0.11],
            [0.006, 0.009, 0.002, 0.33],
            [0.004,0.003, 0.001, 0.008]]
```

I wrote the following code:

```
    def del_list_rate(list):
        list_del = []
        n = 0.2
        d = int(le * (1 - n))
        for list1 in list:
            le = len(list1)
            d = int(le * (1 - n))
            del list1[0 : le-d]
            list_del.append(list1)
```

is there any approach to code it in a faster way?

Comment: Start with writing the code for a single list, later you can extend it for multiple lists. Also, you shared the code but haven't explained that it's not a working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [8]: list
Out[8]:
[[0.002, 0.001, 0.055, 0.44, 0.11, 0.002, 0.001, 0.055, 0.44, 0.11],
 [0.001, 0.006, 0.009, 0.002, 0.33],
 [0.02, 0.004, 0.003, 0.001, 0.008]]

In [9]: [i[int(0.2 * len(i)):] for i in list]
Out[9]:
[[0.055, 0.44, 0.11, 0.002, 0.001, 0.055, 0.44, 0.11],
 [0.006, 0.009, 0.002, 0.33],
 [0.004, 0.003, 0.001, 0.008]]
```

Comment: Thank you bigbounty, only I changed to 0.2 with (1 - 0.2) because I want to preserve with 20% from the elements. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

To improve upon bigbounty's answer, I would suggest the method:

```
def del_list_rate(list):
    return [sublist[int(0.2 * len(sublist)):] for sublist in list]
```